# Adjusted / marginal means estimation in linear mixed effect model in R / Stata

Tags: r, estimation, stata, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

I am a new R user, having some difficulties validating/replicating results from Stata (which a colleague uses) in R.

We are investigating the time (`TIME<-c(1:7)`) course of biomarkers (`BIO<-biomarker`) (repeated measurements over multiple days) in 2000 subjects (`SUBJECT`) in linear multilevel models. The 'basic' structure of the simplest model is:

```
lme(BIO~I(TIME^2), data=data, ~TIME | SUBJECT)
```

What I want to obtain from this are adjusted means (or marginal means) with confidence intervals to plot the time course of the biomarkers. The final model will have additional covariates and interaction terms.

In Stata, my colleague does this using the `margins` command (`margins TIME#TIME`) followed by `marginsplot, x(TIME)`, which yields the desired plot. The estimates I obtain using either `predict()` or `lsmeans()` (the latter providing confidence intervals) differ significantly from those from Stata, although the basic fit of both models is no different.

Any thoughts or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @mattia, I think these two posts ([1](http://gpjacob.blogspot.com/2010/06/multinomial-logit-in-stata-and-r-ii.html), [2](http://gpjacob.blogspot.com/2010/06/multinomial-logit-in-stata-and-r-iii.html)) may be helpful, to translate between `Stata` and `R`.